# Open javamail folder failed

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail, james

I developed an email website using javamail and apache-james and it works well mostly. But some user got Open failed Exception and cannot receive new mail.
The code of receive email:

```
Session mailSession = Session.getInstance(System.getProperties(), null);
mailSession.setDebug(false);
Store store = null;
Folder folder = null; //javax.mail.Folder
try {
    store = mailSession.getStore(SParam.PROTOCOL);
    store.connect(Property.getPop3(), userName, password);
    logger.info("trying to receive emails from james server...");
    folder = store.getFolder("INBOX");
    try {
        if (!folder.isOpen()) {
            folder.open(Folder.READ_WRITE); //the point of throwing the exception
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    //receive email from james server.
} catch (Exception e) {
    logger.error("Email Receive Error!" + StackTraceStr.st2str(e));
    try {
        folder.close(true);
    } catch (Exception e2) {
}
} finally {
    try {
        store.close();
    } catch (Exception cloex) {
    }
}
```

In most cases, it works just fine. But still got the error occasionally:

```
javax.mail.MessagingException: Open failed;
nested exception is:
java.io.IOException: STAT command failed: null
at com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Folder.open(POP3Folder.java:228)
at com.csc.mail.jsh.mail.core.ReceiveMail.receive(ReceiveMail.java:82)
at com.csc.mail.jsh.mail.core.ReceiveMail.run(ReceiveMail.java:222)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: STAT command failed: null
at com.sun.mail.pop3.Protocol.stat(Protocol.java:366)
at com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Folder.open(POP3Folder.java:203)
... 3 more
```

Waiting your help and thanks a lot!

I debug and debug, finally found the STAT command failed! when STAT command got an error, there's an exception of james, but that makes no sence!

```
21/11/12 14:39:16 ERROR pop3server: Exception during connection from 127.0.0.1     
    (127.0.0.1) : An exception occurred getting a database connection.
    org.apache.avalon.framework.CascadingRuntimeException: An exception occurred getting a database connection.
at org.apache.james.userrepository.AbstractJdbcUsersRepository.openConnection(AbstractJdbcUsersRepository.java:617)
    at org.apache.james.userrepository.AbstractJdbcUsersRepository.getUserByName(AbstractJdbcUsersRepository.java:521)
    at org.apache.james.userrepository.AbstractUsersRepository.test(AbstractUsersRepository.java:270)
    at org.apache.james.core.LocalUsersRepository.test(LocalUsersRepository.java:90)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.avalon.phoenix.components.application.BlockInvocationHandler.invoke(BlockInvocationHandler.java:134)
    at $Proxy4.test(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.james.pop3server.POP3Handler.doPASS(POP3Handler.java:537)
    at org.apache.james.pop3server.POP3Handler.parseCommand(POP3Handler.java:479)
    at org.apache.james.pop3server.POP3Handler.handleConnection(POP3Handler.java:277)
    at org.apache.james.util.connection.ServerConnection$ClientConnectionRunner.run(ServerConnection.java:432)
    at org.apache.excalibur.thread.impl.ExecutableRunnable.execute(ExecutableRunnable.java:55)
    at org.apache.excalibur.thread.impl.WorkerThread.run(WorkerThread.java:116)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
    ORA-12519, TNS:no appropriate service handler found
    The Connection descriptor used by the client was: 192.168.250.23:1521:csmis
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:112)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:261)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:387)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:439)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:165)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:35)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:801)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DriverConnectionFactory.createConnection(DriverConnectionFactory.java:37)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnectionFactory.makeObject(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:290)
    at org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:771)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource.getConnection(PoolingDataSource.java:95)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:540)
    at org.apache.james.util.dbcp.JdbcDataSource.getConnection(JdbcDataSource.java:220)
    at org.apache.james.userrepository.AbstractJdbcUsersRepository.openConnection(AbstractJdbcUsersRepository.java:614)
... 15 more
```

All application runs on the same server, and there's only a few users online(when I test it, only me use it). The error just appear occasionally. Why?

Comment: Looks more like a server-side outage that can occure time to time. Is it your server? Is the problem also occuring when you are using a normal mailing program?

Comment: @AlexandreLavoie I'm using [Apache james](http://james.apache.org/). And write a clint-side by myself using javamail. There are about 200 users(using frequently) and 30,000 emails now.

Comment: Have you checked for maximum simultaneous sessions or connections? Like my server in IMAP I've reached many times this kind of limit. Almost every web programs have configurations to set concurrent connections limits.

Comment: Thank you @AlexandreLavoie. But I'm not quite sure because when user "sa" login, all emails can be received successfully(about 35 new mails). But user "yan" could't(138 new mails).

Comment: So your problem is random or is based on specific users? Have you access to server logs?

Comment: @AlexandreLavoie random, I think. It just very weird. The user complained that a few couldn't receive new mails since October 20th. So I checked the log but nothing usefull except exceptions above. I imported the database into laboratory and tested locally, sometimes cannot receive, but sometimes can. I really cannot find the reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had contact with Apache James and finally found the answer. You can find it at here: [STAT command failed occasionally](http://www.mail-archive.com/server-user@james.apache.org/msg14115.html). At the end of the page, the thread had been listed.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a mail server issue. `STAT` command is used to show number of messages. Normally `STAT` is the first command to run after successfully connected to the mail server.

Try to use `mailSession.setDebug(true)` to enter debug mode to get more error logs.

Comment: Seems a good idea. I'll modify it and see what happend. But the log file really exponded quickly. Thank you @AlexCheng

Comment: [2012-11-15 14:22:01] com.csc.mail.jsh.mail.core.ReceiveMail : [INFO ]  - trying to receive emails from james server...
C: STAT
S: -ERR
C: QUIT
S: +OK Apache James POP3 Server signing off.
[2012-11-15 14:22:03] com.csc.mail.jsh.mail.core.ReceiveMail : [ERROR]  - Folder open failed：javax.mail.MessagingException: Open failed;
nested exception is:
    java.io.IOException: STAT command failed: null
    at com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Folder.open(POP3Folder.java:228)
    at com.csc.mail.jsh.mail.core.ReceiveMail.receive(ReceiveMail.java:82)
    at com.csc.mail.jsh.mail.core.ReceiveMail.run...

Comment: [can not receive emails from apache james](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13393347/cant-receive-emails-from-apache-james/13404596#comment18476058_13404596)