# Can't receive emails from Apache James

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail, james

I developed a webmail to link apache james and it works. But some user cannot receive emails from james. I set `mailSession.setDebug(true)` and trace two users' logs(sa can receive, the other cannot). The difference shows below:

the user who can receive email successfully(user sa):

```
[2012-11-15 14:24:12] com.csc.mail.jsh.mail.core.ReceiveMail : [INFO ]  - trying to receive emails from james server...
C: STAT
S: +OK 2 2584
C: NOOP
S: +OK
C: TOP 1 0
S: +OK Message follows
...
```

the other user receive failure(user chai):

```
[2012-11-15 14:22:01] com.csc.mail.jsh.mail.core.ReceiveMail : [INFO ]  - trying to receive emails from james server...
C: STAT
S: -ERR
C: QUIT
S: +OK Apache James POP3 Server signing off.
[2012-11-15 14:22:03] com.csc.mail.jsh.mail.core.ReceiveMail : [ERROR]  - Folder open failed：javax.mail.MessagingException: Open failed;
nested exception is:
    java.io.IOException: STAT command failed: null
    at com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Folder.open(POP3Folder.java:228)
    at com.csc.mail.jsh.mail.core.ReceiveMail.receive(ReceiveMail.java:82)
    at com.csc.mail.jsh.mail.core.ReceiveMail.run(ReceiveMail.java:222)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: STAT command failed: null
    at com.sun.mail.pop3.Protocol.stat(Protocol.java:366)
    at com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Folder.open(POP3Folder.java:203)
    ... 3 more
```

My receive code:

```
Session mailSession = Session.getInstance(System.getProperties(), null);
mailSession.setDebug(true);
Store store = null;
Folder folder = null; //javax.mail.Folder
try {
    store = mailSession.getStore("pop3");
    store.connect(Property.getPop3(), userName, password);
    logger.info("trying to receive emails from james server...");
    folder = store.getFolder("INBOX");
    try {
        if (!folder.isOpen()) {
            folder.open(Folder.READ_WRITE); //the point of throwing the exception
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    //receive email from james server.
} catch (Exception e) {
    logger.error("Email Receive Error!" + StackTraceStr.st2str(e));
    try {
        folder.close(true);
    } catch (Exception e2) {
    }
} finally {
    try {
        store.close();
    } catch (Exception cloex) {
    }
}
```

I had posted a post at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13357204/open-javamail-folder-failed/13358889#13358889). Thanks for your any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had contact with Apache James and finally found the answer. You can find it at here: [STAT command failed occasionally](http://www.mail-archive.com/server-user@james.apache.org/msg14115.html). At the end of the page, the thread had been listed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you started another thread for this...

There's something wrong with your server.  Check the server logs.  It's failing the STAT command but not reporting any reason for the failure.

Comment: Thanks @billshannon. I debug and debug, finally found that when the STAT command got an error, there's an exception of james, but that makes no sence! "ERROR pop3server: Exception during connection from 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) : An exception occurred getting a database connection." All application runs on the same server, and there's only a few users(when I test it, only me use it). Why cannot connect db?

Comment: No idea.  Looks like you need to find an Apache James expert.